# How can I use vImage (Accelerate) framework in iOS from Xamarin?

Tags: ios, xamarin, accelerate-framework, vimage

I want to do some image processing for an iPhone app. I found that vImage is the library (probably in native C) for iOS 5.0 and greater.

How can I use this library if I am using Xamarin for the app development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vImage support is in the Monotouch.Accelerate namespace.  This [sample](http://docs.xamarin.com/samples/UIImageEffects/) from Xamarin utilizes vImage.